# retrieve value from childnodes with minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I am very new to XML and I trying to retrieve the value from childnodes

```
from xml.dom import minidom

def Get_ExtList(progName):
    progFile='%s.xml'%progName
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(progFile)
    extList=[]
    rootNode=xmldoc.firstChild
    progNode=rootNode.childNodes[1]
    for fileNodes in progNode.childNodes:
        newList=[]      
        for formatNodes in fileNodes.childNodes:        
            for nodes in formatNodes.childNodes:
                x=nodes.toxml()
                x=' '.join(x.split())
                newList.append(str(x))
        extList.append(newList)     
    print extList
```

Output:

```
[[], [‘.aaa'], [], [‘.bbb'], [], [‘.ccc'], [], [‘.ddd'], [], [‘.xxx', ‘.yyy'], []]
```

but I want something as follows

```
[[‘.aaa'], [‘.bbb'],[‘.ccc’],[‘.ddd'],[‘.xxx', ‘.yyy']]
```

Here is a sample file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<program>
  <progname name="TEST">
    <file>
      <format>
        .aaa
      </format>
    </file>
    <file>
      <format>
        .bbb
      </format>
    </file>
    <file>
      <format>
        .ccc
      </format>
    </file>
    <file>
      <format>
        .ddd
      </format>
    </file>
    <file>
      <format>
        .xxx
      </format>
      <format>
        .yyy
      </format>
    </file>
  </progname>
</program>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping not only through nodes that contain `<file>` tags (`ELEMENT_NODE` node type), but also indentation white space (`TEXT_NODE` node type). For example in this element:

```
<a>
  <b>c</b>
</a>
```

There are three elements:

- `TEXT_NODE` with value `\n__` (spaces indicated with `_`)
- `ELEMENT_NODE` with value `<b>c</b>`
- `TEXT_NODE` with value `\n`

If that file was formatted differently: `<a><b>c</b></a>` there would be only one `ELEMENT_NODE` inside.

You could for example skip these nodes:

```
for fileNodes in progNode.childNodes:    
    if fileNodes.nodeType != fileNodes.ELEMENT_NODE:    
        continue
```

or check wether `newList` was created for correct node and add it's contents only for `ELEMENT_NODE`:

```
    if fileNodes.nodeType == fileNodes.ELEMENT_NODE:    
        extList.append(newList)
```

otherwise you would get empty list `[]` appended.

Answer (score 0):

DOM nodes can be elements, text, or even comments. Also note that `toxml` should not be used to extract text content. Instead, use the `.data` property of text nodes:

```
for nodes in formatNodes.childNodes:
    if node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE:
        tns =(tn.data for tn in node.childNodes if tn.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE)
        newList.append(''.join(tns).strip())
```

Comment: I have been able to run the code with modifications but the trim function does not work. it gives the following error                     AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute ‘trim’                 So I have to use the split to get it work. The above code looks very neat but if I can get it to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @shabana Oops, confused `trim` with `strip`. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could try to process the list and delete empty elements:

```
>>> list = [[], ['.inp'], [], ['.mdp'], [], ['.xtc'], [], ['.top'], [], ['.gro', '.pdb'], []]
>>> for i in list:
...   if not i:
...     list.remove(i)
... 
>>> list
[['.inp'], ['.mdp'], ['.xtc'], ['.top'], ['.gro', '.pdb']]
```

Comment: I have been doing it. But I am sure there should be a better way to extract the node values. I feel my approach is not the best and I am doing this with very little knowledge of XML format.